# Understanding a sbt error when executing the package command

Tags: scala, sbt

Can someone help me understand why this command:

```
$ sbt package clean
```

Results in the following error?

```
[error] [/Users/slinky66/ScalaApps/WordCount2/wordcount2.sbt]:1: ';' expected but '.' found.
```

**The .sbt file**

```
## wordcount2.sbt
name := "Word Count Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"
```

Thanks

Comment: you have `##` as comment plus are you able to get the spark, with 2.12. I don't think its available - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `## wordcount2.sbt` from the .sbt file. comments must begin with `//` not with `#`. ie it should be

```
// wordcount2.sbt
name := "Word Count Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"
```

Comment: And probably you would need scalac 2.11.* not 2.12 for spark - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.12/